# Glyphs: hide & show image in background

Tags: font-design, glyphs

I have placed a reference image in Glyphs in order to draw paths on top of it. Is there a way hide the image and show it again (in other words turn on and off my reference)?

Comment: Yes, but I can't remember now and I'm not in front of a computer right now... I'm pretty sure it's there in one of the menus though.

Comment: @Cai Hi and thanks for responding, I have already found the solution, its quite simple, I've posted a screenshot below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem: Under the menu tab `View` the option `Show images` is provided.

[image]